# Почему сайты пингуются, но в браузере не открываются?

Tags: windows, windows-7, локальная-сеть

Есть проблема на одном из компьютеров на ОС Win 7 Home, пропадает интернет, сайты пингуются, но в браузере не открываются. При переподключение локального соединения сайты грузятся до определенного момента, потом все по новой.

Comment: вирусы лечили?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, какие DNS серверы прописаны на адаптере. Есть подозрения на вирусы.И подробнее о карте сети (как ПК подключён к интернету). Если через маршрутизатор, то проверьте настройки DNS и DHCP на нём.

Answer (score 1):

Решение твоей проблемы: [Сброс параметров протокола Интернета (TCP/IP)](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/299357)